# How do I overcome type 'exception' does not exist error?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have function in oracle db and trying to migrate to postgresql.I have not added the full function as rest of the lines throw no errors.
Here's what i have got so far, but i am getting an error

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_nightly_jobs_pkg_profs_load () RETURNS varchar AS $body$
DECLARE
load_failed exception;
intTempCount bigint;
strMessage varchar(1000);
intProfsCount bigint;
BEGIN
select count(*)into STRICT intTempCount from profs_temp;
 if (intTempCount< 300000) then
strMessage := 'PROFS Load Failed. The Temp Profs table only has '||intTempCount||' records.';
      raise load_failed;
   end if
```

This is the error I am getting

> Error : type ''exception'' does not exist
> Line 3 : load_failed exception;

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE

Comment: I doubt that this code actually does something; declaration of all variables looks *wrong* (missing spaces). Anyway: if EXCEPTION doesn't work in PostgreSQL, remove that line entirely and see what happens.

Comment: Check now @Littlefoot